# Create new array with matched values with it's sum in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below type of array, now I want to match the value before underscore and sum the values after underscore and store it into the new array with matched key.

```
let myarray = [];
myarray[0] = "25_5";
myarray[1] = "125_15";
myarray[2] = "25_10";
myarray[3] = "125_30";
```

**Expected output**

```
matchedArr[25] = 15
matchedArr[125] = 45
```

I tried below code

```
this.myarray.forEach((i) => {
        let arr = i.split("_");
        let key = arr[0];
        let price = arr[1];
        console.log(key+' =  '+price);
      });
```

Comment: you forgot the attempt - Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Bravo I added the code which I tried

Comment: console.log isn't going to fill a new array or add prices

Comment: @Bravo Yes I know that, but I didn't get the actual idea how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a fairly simple `reduce`

```js
let myarray = [];
myarray[0] = "25_5";
myarray[1] = "125_15";
myarray[2] = "25_10";
myarray[3] = "125_30";

const result = myarray.reduce( (acc, i) => {
    const [key,value] = i.split("_");
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + parseInt(value,10);
    return acc;
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do sort of what you want

Are you sure you want the output to be an array though?

```js
let myarray = [];
myarray[0] = "25_5";
myarray[1] = "125_15";
myarray[2] = "25_10";
myarray[3] = "125_30";

let matchedArray=myarray.reduce((a,i)=>{
  const [k,v]=i.split('_');
  a[k]=(a[k]||0)+ +v;
  return a;
},[]);
console.log(matchedArray);
```

if you replace `,[])` with `,{})` you'll get a much more useful result